# my ajax post function keeps failing

Tags: jquery, ajax

My script works up to the point of getting the values of the checkboxes the user has selected, but fails when I need to send those values to my action in my controller. There is obviously something wrong with the code for posting but I'm new to ajax and json so I'm not sure what to do.

```
function getValueUsingClass()
{

    var chkArray = $(".chk:checked").map(function ()
    {
        return this.value;
    }).get(); 


    if (chkArray.length > 1)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action(\"Charter\", \"StateController\")", // My controller name and action name
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'randstuff': chkArray }) 
        }).done(function ()
        {

        }).fail(function ()
        { 
            alert("Error!");
        });
    } else
    {
        alert("Please check at least one of the checkbox");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: is this code in a javascript file or asp view file? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab for more clues ...status, what is sent, url, what is returned etc

Comment: define 'something wrong' - do you see a console error before execution? do you see that the request fails in the inspector network tab? (implying a server side error or bad post URL) does nothing happen? do you always hit the `.fail()` function?

Comment: i always hit the fail function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using ASP .NET MVC, check the generated javascript in your browser.

It seems like the URL is not being generated properly in this line:

```
"@Url.Action(\"Charter\", \"StateController\")"
```

I don't have a Windows machine now, but I think that is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
'@Url.Action("Charter", "StateController")'
```

Also, shows us the errors your are getting in the javascript console in your browser so we can help you. Many other things could be wrong.

Comment: if it is even compiled at all which it wouldn't be if it's in a javascript file

Comment: escaped quotes should be fine?

Comment: I assumed this is in an ASP page, not in a javascript file. And that he is using razor engine (due to the @ symbol used and the method)

Comment: Just trying to help, if I get more information I will edit my answer.

Comment: yes, it is asp.net mvc...and this is the code in the javascript file

Comment: Then your URL is wrong, type the URL manually, without Url.Action( ) method. And test that first.

Comment: did this help at all? @lagfvu

Comment: @cacho, yes, it works now that i remove that. Thanks

Comment: @lagfvu if my answer helped, pleased mark this as the correct answer and/or upvote this answer. If you are a new user here in StackOverflow, please take this [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the site.